# nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "*": Connection refused (Connection refused);

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was trying to access Rest API from my application. When that API is not online, my application occurred above mentioned error. I am using spring boot. I want to know that, is there any way to check the availability of the url before accessing it.

```
 String URL = "http://172.17.42.1:4001/v2/keys" + key + "/running";
 instance = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, Instance.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know the availability of the service you have to hit the URL, there is no other way.

However, [spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix) is built to handle these kinds of problems.

[Circuit Breaker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/)  docs

> Netflix’s Hystrix library provides an implementation of the Circuit
>   Breaker pattern: when we apply a circuit breaker to a method, Hystrix
>   watches for failing calls to that method, and if failures build up to
>   a threshold, Hystrix opens the circuit so that subsequent calls
>   automatically fail. While the circuit is open, Hystrix redirects calls
>   to the method, and they’re passed on to our specified fallback method

There is so many material out there to learn from.

- [Hystrix Circuit Breaker Pattern – Spring Cloud](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-cloud/spring-hystrix-circuit-breaker-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the exact answer which i was looking

Comment: Happy to help :)